# Bioequivalent drugs in the US and EU?

Tags: data-request, medical

I'm looking for lists of bioequivalent drugs in the US or EU. I know there is a (quite short) list from the Chilean government at http://datos.gob.cl/datasets/ver/1303 but I'd like to know if there is something similar in other countries.

Answer (score 1):

A useful subset of the bioequivalent drugs would be approved generics. Don't know if you're also looking for unapproved (yet) but these would be a bit harder to find as a complete collection. Keep in mind that the pharmacokinetic test routines differ slightly between the US and Europe.

Keeping to the approved generics, the FDA is required to maintain and post [a list](http://www.fda.gov/drugs/developmentapprovalprocess/howdrugsaredevelopedandapproved/approvalapplications/abbreviatednewdrugapplicationandagenerics/ucm126389.htm) quarterly. The data is in PDF but at least it's selectable text (not just scanned images). For Europe, the EMA has a [search page](http://www.ema.europa.eu/ema/index.jsp?curl=pages/medicines/landing/epar_search.jsp&murl=menus/medicines/medicines.jsp&mid=WC0b01ac058001d124&searchTab=searchByAuthType&alreadyLoaded=true&isNewQuery=true&status=Authorised&status=Withdrawn&status=Suspended&status=Refused&keyword=Enter%20keywords&searchType=name&taxonomyPath=&treeNumber=&searchGenericType=generics&genericsKeywordSearch=Submit) for generics (etc). Search results can be downloaded in excel format.